# Gatsby createresolvers function is giving out an error during gatsby build

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to upgrade my project from gatsby v3 to gatsby v5 while everything was going smootly, I've encountered an error saying

```
ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL.UNKNOWN

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

pagePaths is not defined

  204 |       elements {
  205 |         third_party_url {
  206 |           value
  207 |         }
  208 |       }
  209 |     }
  210 |     ... on kontent_item_layout___master_page {
  211 |       elements {
  212 |         slug {
  213 |           value
> 214 |           url
      |           ^
  215 |         }
  216 |       }
  217 |     }
  218 |     ... on kontent_item_document___general {
  219 |       elements {
  220 |         document {
  221 |           value {
  222 |             url
  223 |           }
  224 |         }

File path: D:/javascriptProjects/Frontend/website/src/templates/Page.tsx
Url path: /customer-service/contact-us/
Plugin: none



  ReferenceError: pagePaths is not defined

  - gatsby-node.js:169 resolver
    D:/javascriptProjects/Frontend/website/gatsby-node.js:169:29

  - resolvers.ts:751 wrappedTracingResolver
    [website]/[gatsby]/src/schema/resolvers.ts:751:20
```

This error comes in almost all graphql queries which contains url. I've tried seeing gatsby documentation but was of not much help.

here is my project structure

package.json

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@babylonjs/core": "6.10.0",
        "@babylonjs/gui": "6.10.0",
        "@babylonjs/loaders": "6.10.0",
        "@kontent-ai/gatsby-components": "^10.0.0",
        "@kontent-ai/gatsby-source": "^10.0.0",
        "@loadable/component": "^5.15.2",
        "@rshackleton/gatsby-transformer-kontent-image": "^2.1.0",
        "@types/react-modal": "^3.12.0",
        "algoliasearch": "^4.18.0",
        "axios": "^0.25.0",
        "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
        "framer-motion": "^6.2.6",
        "gatsby": "^5.11.0",
        "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-algolia": "^1.0.3",
        "gatsby-plugin-breakpoints": "^1.3.6",
        "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^5.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^6.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-readingtime": "^3.0.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.7.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^6.11.0",
        "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^6.11.0",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.11.0",
        "html-react-parser": "^4.0.0",
        "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.24",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "postcss-url": "^10.1.3",
        "proxy-polyfill": "^0.3.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
        "react-babylonjs": "3.1.17",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dropdown": "^1.9.2",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-hook-form": "^7.45.1",
        "react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.22.0",
        "react-jotform-embed": "^1.1.3",
        "react-modal": "^3.14.3",
        "react-player": "^2.9.0",
        "react-select": "^5.2.2",
        "react-toastify": "^8.2.0",
        "react-truncate": "^2.4.0",
        "sharp": "^0.30.1",
        "typescript-plugin-css-modules": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack": "^5.69.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.4",
        "@loadable/babel-plugin": "^5.13.2",
        "@loadable/webpack-plugin": "^5.15.2",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.0.24",
        "@storybook/react": "^7.0.24",
        "@svgr/webpack": "^6.2.1",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.1",
        "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
        "@types/react-autosuggest": "^10.0.1",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
        "@types/react-instantsearch-dom": "^6.12.2",
        "@types/react-truncate": "^2.3.3",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-jest": "29.5.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
        "babel-preset-gatsby": "^2.7.0",
        "chalk": "^5.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.21.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
        "cypress": "^9.5.0",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-webpack-bundle-analyser-v2": "^1.1.27",
        "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
        "husky": "^4.3.6",
        "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
        "inquirer": "^7.1.0",
        "jest": "^29.1.1",
        "jest-junit": "^12.2.0",
        "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
        "npm-force-resolutions": "0.0.3",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "postcss-custom-properties": "^12.1.4",
        "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.2",
        "postcss-mixins": "^9.0.1",
        "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.4.0",
        "prettier": "^2.3.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
        "storybook-css-modules-preset": "^1.1.1",
        "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
        "yargs-parser": "^21.0.0"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.0-experimental-c8b778b7f-20220825": {
            "react": "^18.2.0"
        },
        "react-truncate": {
            "react": "^18.2.0"
        },
        "@rshackleton/gatsby-transformer-kontent-image": {
            "gatsby": "^5.11.0",
            "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.11.0"
        }
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "gatsby": "^5.11.0"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "gatsby"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "main": "n/a",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run develop",
        "develop": "gatsby develop",
        "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-pattern public .",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:ci": "CI=true jest --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "e2e": "cypress open",
        "e2e:ci": "cypress run",
        "e2e:verify": "cypress verify",
        "e2e:clean": "cypress cache clear",
        "format": "prettier --trailing-comma es5 --single-quote --write 'src/**/*' 'bin/*.js'",
        "build": "cross-env GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_PAGE_BUILD_ON_DATA_CHANGES=true gatsby build --log-pages",
        "serve": "gatsby serve",
        "clean": "gatsby clean",
        "fix-semi": "eslint --quiet --ignore-pattern node_modules --ignore-pattern public --parser babel-eslint --no-eslintrc --rule '{\"semi\": [2, \"never\"], \"no-extra-semi\": [2]}' --fix *.js bin/*.js",
        "setup": "node ./bin/setup.js",
        "start": "npm run develop",
        "heroku-postbuild": "gatsby build",
        "cleanup-repository": "yarn remove contentful-import chalk inquirer && node ./bin/cleanup.js && rimraf bin contentful",
        "copy-static-queries": "cp -r ./public/page-data/sq/d ./public/static",
        "prestorybook": "npm run copy-static-queries",
        "storybook": "NODE_ENV=test start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src/stories/assets,./static/",
        "build-storybook": "NODE_ENV=test build-storybook"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "react-error-overlay": "6.0.11"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --cache --fix",
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css}": "prettier --write"
    },
    "jest-junit": {
        "outputDirectory": "test/results/",
        "outputName": "unit.xml"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=18.0.0"
    }
}
```

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { COUNTRY } = process.env;
const languages = COUNTRY ? require(`./languages-${COUNTRY}.json`) : require('./languages.json');
var myredirects = require('./urlRedirects.json');
const nonEnglishLang = languages.filter((lang) => !lang.includes('en') && !lang.includes('default'))
combineRedirects = () => {
  let countryUrlRedirect = require(`./urlRedirects-${COUNTRY}.json`)
  let combinedRedirects = [...myredirects, ...countryUrlRedirect]

  myredirects = Object.values(combinedRedirects.reduce((result, { fromPath, ...rest }) => {
    result[fromPath] = { ...(result[fromPath] || {}), fromPath, ...rest };
    return result;
  }, {}));
}

if (COUNTRY) {
  combineRedirects()
}

exports.onPostBuild = ({ reporter }) => {
  reporter.info(`Your Gatsby site has been built!`);
};

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig();

  if (stage === 'develop' || stage === 'build-javascript') {
    const miniCssExtractPlugin = config.plugins.find(
      (plugin) => plugin.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin'
    );
    if (miniCssExtractPlugin) {
      miniCssExtractPlugin.options.ignoreOrder = true;
    }
  }

  if (stage === 'build-javascript') {
    // // Ensure Gatsby does not do any css code splitting
    config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.styles.priority = 10;

    // remove babylonjs from commons chunk as it's only used
    // on two components on the product pages
    config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups.commons = {
      minChunks: 2,
      priority: 20,
      test(module) {
        if (module.resource && module.resource.includes('@babylonjs')) {
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    };

  }
  actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config);

};

/* In this function we take all the page paths of every single country and and combine all of them into a single array pageTrees after this we loop through each path and all the
paths in an array pageTrees such that if we have COUNTRY env then give priority to the path of that country and make that path as default (us) and remove the orignal default pagepath
this will make Australia and Newzealand to have default paths without having au-en in them
*/

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage, createRedirect } = actions;
  myredirects.forEach((redirect) => {
    createRedirect({
      fromPath: redirect.fromPath,
      toPath: redirect.toPath,
      redirectInBrowser: true,
      isPermanent: true,
    });
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const masterPageTemplate = path.resolve('./src/templates/Page.tsx');
    resolve(
      graphql(KontentSpotlightPageQuery).then((result) => {
        if (result.errors) {
          console.log(result.errors);
          reject(result.errors);
        }

        const pageTrees = createPageTrees(result);

        let defaultCountryIndex = pageTrees.findIndex(pageTree => pageTree[0].lang === 'default')
        if (defaultCountryIndex > 0) {
          pageTrees.unshift(...pageTrees.splice(defaultCountryIndex, 1))
        }

        var combinedPagePaths = pageTrees.reduce((prev, curr) => {
          return prev.concat(curr);
        }, []);

        let priorityCombinedPagePaths = []
        combinedPagePaths.forEach((pageTree) => {
          let foundObjIndexInPriorityPaths = priorityCombinedPagePaths.findIndex(
            (tree) => tree.slug === pageTree.slug
          );
          if (foundObjIndexInPriorityPaths > -1 && COUNTRY && pageTree.lang.toLowerCase().includes(`${COUNTRY}-`) && !priorityCombinedPagePaths[foundObjIndexInPriorityPaths].priority) {

            let defaultPagePathIndex = pageTrees[0].findIndex((tree) => tree.slug == pageTree.slug)
            if (defaultPagePathIndex > - 1) {
              pageTrees[0][defaultPagePathIndex].id = pageTree.id
            }


            pageTree.lang = "default"
            pageTree.priority = true
            priorityCombinedPagePaths[foundObjIndexInPriorityPaths] = pageTree
          }
          else if (foundObjIndexInPriorityPaths == -1) {
            if (COUNTRY && pageTree.lang.toLowerCase().includes(`${COUNTRY}-`)) {
              pageTree.lang = "default"
              pageTree.priority = true
            } else if (nonEnglishLang.map((lang) => pageTree.path.startsWith(`/${lang.toLowerCase()}`))) {
              let modifiedPathForNonEngLang = {
                ...pageTree,
                path: pageTree.path.replace(nonEnglishLang.map((lang) => `/${lang.toLowerCase()}`), ''),
              }
              priorityCombinedPagePaths.push(modifiedPathForNonEngLang)
            } else {
              priorityCombinedPagePaths.push(pageTree)
            }
          }
        })

        var pagePaths = extractPagePaths(priorityCombinedPagePaths)
        // Create all pages from pageTree using Gatsby's createPage
        pageTrees.forEach((tree) => {
          tree.forEach((page) => {
            createPage({
              path: page.path,
              component: masterPageTemplate,
              context: {
                id: page.id,
                slug: page.slug,
                paths: pagePaths,
                treelang: page.lang,
                languages: languages,
              },
            });
          });
        });
      })
    );
  });
};

exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }, ...props) => {
  console.log(props)
  const resolvers = {
    kontent_item_url_slug_element_value: {
      url: {
        type: "String",
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          let langPrefix = '';
          let lang = '';
          if (
            context &&
            context.context &&
            context.context.treelang &&
            context.context.treelang != 'default' &&
            context.context.treelang.split('-')[0].toLowerCase() === COUNTRY
          ) {
            lang = context.context.treelang.toLowerCase();
            langPrefix = `/${lang}`;
          }
          let url =
            `${langPrefix}${pagePaths[source.value]}` ||
            `${langPrefix}/${source.value}` ||
            '/';

          return url;
          //example values
          // langPrefix /nz-en
          // pagePaths[source.value] /infrared-sauna-health-benefits/heart-health
          // source.value heart-health
        },
      },
      web_spotlight: {
        type: 'Boolean!',
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          let webSpotlightExists = !!source.value;
          return webSpotlightExists;
        },
      },
    },
  };
  createResolvers(resolvers);
};

exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;
  const typedefs = `
  type kontent_item_rich_text_element_link implements Node {
    url_slug: String
    codenamme: String
    link_id: String
    type: String
  }
  `;
  createTypes(typedefs)
}

function createPageTrees(result) {

  const homePages = result.data.allKontentItemHomepage.edges;
  const pagePaths = homePages.map(createPageTree);
  createPageTrees.cache = pagePaths
  return pagePaths
}

/* 
    Create a page tree to build paths for all pages esults in array of config objects for createPage along with the content id
    for each page.
    example config object
        { 
            id: '0000-0000-0000-0000',
            path: '/url/path/to/page/page-slug', 
            slug: 'page-slug'
        }
*/
function createPageTree(edge) {
  const homePage = edge.node;
  const homeSlug = homePage.elements.content.value[0]
    ? homePage.elements.content.value[0].elements.slug.value
    : null;
  const homeId = homePage.elements.content.value[0]
    ? homePage.elements.content.value[0].id
    : null;
  const isDefault = COUNTRY && homePage.preferred_language.split('-')[0].toLowerCase() === COUNTRY || homePage.preferred_language === 'default' ? true : false

  const languageCode = homePage.preferred_language.toLowerCase();
  const initialPath = isDefault ? '/' : `/${languageCode}`;

  if (!homeSlug || !homeId) {
    return [];
  }

  // initialize page tree with Homepage
  const pageTree = [
    {
      id: homeId,
      path: initialPath,
      slug: homeSlug,
      lang: homePage.preferred_language,
    },
  ];

  makePageTree(
    homePage.elements.subpages.value,
    isDefault ? '' : initialPath
  );
  // recursively generate page tree
  function makePageTree(subPages, prevPath = '') {
    subPages.forEach((subPage) => {
      const pageSlug = subPage.elements?.slug.value;
      const newPath = `${prevPath}/${pageSlug}`;
      if (!pageSlug) {
        return;
      }
      pageTree.push({
        id: subPage.id,
        path: newPath,
        slug: pageSlug,
        lang: subPage.preferred_language,
      });
      if (
        subPage &&
        subPage.elements &&
        subPage.elements.subpages &&
        subPage.elements.subpages.value.length
      ) {
        makePageTree(subPage.elements.subpages.value, newPath);
      }
    });
  }
  return pageTree;
}

// Map page id's to the pages real path
// returns array of
// { id: '0000-0000-0000-0000', path: '/example/nested/path' }
function extractPagePaths(paths) {
  const pathMap = {};
  paths.forEach((path) => {
    pathMap[path.slug] = path.path;
  });
  return pathMap;
}

const KontentSpotlightPageQuery = `
{
  allKontentItemHomepage(filter: {system: {workflow_step: {ne: "archived"}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        elements {
          content {
            value {
              ... on kontent_item_layout___master_page {
                id
                elements {
                  slug {
                    value
                  }
                }
                preferred_language
              }
              preferred_language
            }
          }
          subpages {
            value {
              ... on kontent_item_layout___master_page {
                id
                elements {
                  slug {
                    value
                  }
                  subpages {
                    value {
                      ... on kontent_item_layout___master_page {
                        id
                        elements {
                          slug {
                            value
                          }
                          subpages {
                            value {
                              ... on kontent_item_layout___master_page {
                                id
                                elements {
                                  slug {
                                    value
                                  }
                                  subpages {
                                    value {
                                      ... on kontent_item_layout___master_page {
                                        id
                                        elements {
                                          slug {
                                            value
                                          }
                                          subpages {
                                            value {
                                              ... on kontent_item_layout___master_page {
                                                id
                                                elements {
                                                  slug {
                                                    value
                                                  }
                                                }
                                                preferred_language
                                              }
                                              preferred_language
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                        preferred_language
                                      }
                                      preferred_language
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                                preferred_language
                              }
                              preferred_language
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        preferred_language
                      }
                      preferred_language
                    }
                  }
                }
                preferred_language
              }
              preferred_language
            }
          }
        }
        preferred_language
      }
    }
  }
}
`;
```

I believe i'm going wrong somewhere at createpages or createResolvers. The project runs on gatsby develop but fails on gatsby build. The same query used to work for my gatsby 3 but after  the upgrade it doesn't work